# "gbak: ERROR:unsuccessful metadata update gbak: ERROR: key size exceeds implementation restriction for index"

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I'm performing this command:

```bash
sudo ./gbak -c -user SYSDBA -password a 
/media/diegoeddy/dados/banco_dados/CACONDE2007_25052023.fbk 
/media/diegoeddy/dados/banco_dados/caconde2505202301.fdb
```

However, I am getting this error:

> gbak: ERROR:    key size exceeds implementation restriction for index "USUARIO_ROTINA_IDX3"

How do I solve it? I am using Firebird 2.5.

Answer (score 2):

Increase page size using [-page_size command line switch](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/gbak/firebird-gbak.html#gbak-cmdline-restore).